# Плагин для загрузки изображения в WYSIWYG редактор

Tags: php, javascript, html, ckeditor, tinymce

Есть ли плагин или иное решение для *tinyMCE* или *CKeditor*'а для загрузки изображений на сервер "на лету"? Т.е при копировании текста с картинкой и вставке в редактор, изображение скачивается в заранее заданную папку и сохраняется под уникальным именем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У *CKEditor* есть *CKFinder* (https://cksource.com/ckfinder/demo#ckfinder2), только большой минус: он **платный**.
В нем есть менеджер картинок, многопоточная загрузка, организация подпапок и возможность загружать в заранее указанную папку... Вобщем довольно мощная штука. Но он **платный** :(
я не знаю о существовании других плагинов для *CKEditor* для работы с картинками.

*про tinyMCE не скажу - не использую*

Comment: Спасибо! Посмотрю, если там есть необходимый функционал то вопрос о финансах не встанет)

Comment: смотря что Вам нужно... сохранять в заранее оговоренную папку точно можно. В смысле, это можно сделать через настройки. А вот насчет уникального имени - это не уверен. В конце концов Вы даете пользователю файл менеджер, он сам добавляет/удаляет файлы... и следовательно сам управляет именами

Comment: Ну вообще то идея более "изощренная" -  допусти копировать со страницы сайта контент в котором текст и фото и при клике по кнопке сохранить все фото в редакторе скачиваются в папку (заранее заданную по умолчанию) так чтоб в итоге фото из внешнего ресурса имело вид ../images/temp/img1.jpg вместо http://othersite.com/img/img1.jpg.

Comment: возможно идея не реализуема средствами php или javascript но все таки пока пытаюсь найти хотя бы приближенное решение. Т.к когда работаешь с очень большими объемами контента на процедуру пере сохранения фото уходит много времени

Comment: ну тогда WYSIWYG редактор Вам понадобиться лишь ПОСЛЕ того, как все скачается. Т.е. средствами php Вы скачиваете html страницу; берете из нее все `img src`, скачиваете их по одной в определенную папку; меняете html, чтобы картинки ссылались на эту внутреннюю папку. К той же папке Вы подключите CKFinder. И лишь после этого пользователь сможет редактировать текст и картинки. Я к тому, что если Вы хотели, чтобы редактор скачивал все за Вас с url, включая картинки, то я не думаю, что есть такое web-решение. Проще самому написать...